# Neo4J: How can I repeat my query on all resulting nodes?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, blockchain, bitcoin

so I've started working on a project for my Bachelor Thesis and therefore I'm looking for some help with Cypher since I've hadn't had any touchpoints with it yet!

I've got the BTC Blockchain as my DB and now I want to use the Multi Input Clustering Heuristic to identify all addresses that belong to a person. This means that I want to identify all Transactions from a BTC Wallet that have more than one input address. Once I have the transactions identified, I am looking for the wallets. This is what the following query does:

```
MATCH(a:Address{address:"3QQdfAaPhP1YqLYMBS59BqWjcpXjXVP1wi"})-[:SENDS]-(tx)-[:SENDS]-(a2)

RETURN a2
```

Now that I have these wallets I want to repeat the exact process on these wallets as well and their resulting wallets and so on! So I need a recursive Query which returns me all wallets that where used as Input Wallets at some point.

**Note:**
[Example of an Address that has 2 transactions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkLzJ.png)

This how a the graph of an BTC wallet looks like that received and sent BTC. There are 3 types of nodes (Transactions, Addresses, Blocks).

Comment: The image helped conceptualize your question - thanks for including it. But, what are the labels? I assume that purple are `:Address` nodes, blue are `:Block` nodes, and orange are `:Transaction` nodes, but please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Good on you for using a graph db in your thesis! This isn't related to your question, but to help improve your cypher performance, consider including directions to your relationships and labels on the nodes. E.g., `(a:Address)-[:SENDS]->(tx:Transaction)`.

Comment: @BDT Yes you understand everything correctly! I should have explained the model further in my thread. 
Also thanks for helping me in improving my Cypher performance. I‘m a Newbie and so I am still learning!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand fully, but would the following work to return more than 1 input address?

```cypher
MATCH (a:Address)-[:SENDS*2..]->(tx:Transaction)
WITH DISTINCT a
// Do something with these address
RETURN a.address // or whatever
```

For the record, it's not recommended to have an infinite path like `*2..`. You're better off putting a max value, like `*2..10`, which will limit the returning path to anywhere between 2 and 10 hops.